# Android - HELP moving away from builtin SQLite to Ormlite

Tags: android, sqlite, database-migration, ormlite

I have an `SQLite database` that I created in Android that I'm manually managing all the code for to perform my reading and writing. I recently discovered `ORMlite`. I want to use `ORMlite` to manage my database from this point forward. The issue is the application is already on the android market and I don't want my user's to lose their data.

Is there a way I can tell `ORMlite` to start managing the already made database? Or is there a standard practice to read all of my data from the old database and write it to a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after doing a fair amount of due diligence I realized how simple of a task this is. `Ormlite` actually sits on top of the built-in SQLite. No code is needed to move to `Ormlite`. I simple reference my database name within my `Ormlite Helper Class`.
My code is below. I hope this helps someone else in the future.

```
public class OrmHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    private Context context;

    public OrmHelper(Context context) {
        //references my Sqlite dbnames. I made them static in the SqlHelper class
        super(context, DataBase.DB_Name, null, DataBase.DB_Version);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try {
            Log.i(TAG, "Creating database in Ormlite");
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Model.class);
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, UserCredential.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating database", e);
        }
   }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource,
        int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    /**
     * this genric method is for grabbing the Dao for any ormlite table
     */
    public <T, V> Dao<T, V> getTypeDao(Class<T> classType, Class<V> idType)
           throws SQLException{
        return getDao(classType);
    }
}
```